# Commerce : adding optional insurance block to shopping cart form : ajax callback

Tags: commerce, ajax

Customers will be purposed **an optional insurance** in the shopping cart, calculated as a percentage of Cart Total. I added this feature as an editable field in a footer view of the shopping cart, and I'm **trying to setup ajax callback** to update the cart.

**EDIT** (@people who already read the question) : I solved the initial bugs, so this is a clean update. **You can jump to item 7** if you don't want to read the full implementation...

What I've done so far :

1. Created an *insurance taxonomy*, each term is an insurance option with a % decimal fields (in order to allow insurance options *changes* at any time).
2. Added this taxonomy to the order fields with a *term reference field* "Insurance" .
3. Created a very simple *view block* called `cart_field_assurances` with that Insurance field, with editable format.
4. Installed [Cart View Override](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_view_override), cloned shoppping cart form and set that clone as shopping cart
5. Created a `views-view--commerce-cart-form-assurances.tpl.php` template with :

   ```
   print $rows;
   print views_embed_view('cart_field_assurances', 'block');
   ```
6. Moved insurance view before `#edit-actions` div with Jquery

   ```
   var insurance = $('.view-id-cart_field_assurances').detach();
   insurance.prependTo('#edit-actions');
   ```
7. Removed action buttons, added ajax to the field, declared insurance price component

   ```
   function vts_insurance_form_views_form_cart_field_assurances_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     $ajax = array(
       'callback' => 'vts_insurance_cart_refresh', 
       'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber', 'message' => ''),
     );
     $form['field_order_assurances'][0]['field_order_assurances']['und']['#ajax'] = $ajax;
     //Hide buttons
     $form['field_order_assurances'][0]['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'] = array('hidden');
     $form['actions']['#attributes']['class'] = array('hidden'); 
   }

   //ajax callback
   function vts_insurance_cart_refresh(&$form, &$form_state) {
     //Load the order
     $view = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
     $order_id = $view->result[0]->order_id;
     $order =  commerce_order_load($order_id);         
     //set new value
     $order->field_order_assurances['und'][0]['tid'] = $form_state['values']['field_order_assurances'][0]['field_order_assurances']['und'][0]['tid'];
     commerce_order_save($order);
   }

   //insurance price component
   function vts_insurance_commerce_price_component_type_info() {
     return array(
       'insurance' => array(
         'title' => t('Insurances'), 
         'display_title' => t('Insurances'), 
         'weight' => -10,
       ), 
     );
   }
   ```
8. Set up a rule : Before saving a commerce order, calculate the insurance amount and add it to total as an *Insurances price component*

### To illustrate, this is the shopping cart form, with the optional insurance field below

[image: Drupal Commerce optional insurance]

### The question

How to refresh the display of "Cart Commerce Order total" shopping form view (and its price components of course) in `vts_insurance_cart_refresh` ajax callback ?

Comment: Which cart module are you using Kojo?

Comment: `commerce_order_save(my_order);` looks like a syntax error `$my_order` vs `my_order` is missing a `$` You should post your actual code if you want people to help debug it.

Comment: @Darvanen, I use Commerce native `commerce_cart.module` plus *Commerce Cart Ajax*.

Comment: @DavidThomas, indeed, there was a typo in the question, tks. So I updated it with the full code. But at the moment the pbs begin even without this custom code, so it seems there's a pb when you add a footer to the shopping cart view ...

Comment: @kojo, ok without going into too much detail, you'd be better to use the commerce api, create a checkout pane with `hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info` and a price component with `hook_commerce_price_component_type_info`

Comment: @DavidThomas, tks for your suggestions. Nevertheless as explained above, I'd prefer to put this option in the cart form, and I'm very close to manage it, except this ajax mistake. So I'd really like to **debug why ajax cart does not return the full shopping cart** but only the footer I added, before going for a checkout pane or whatever. Tks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement an optional insurance field in the shopping cart : first, follow question steps 1 to 6.

For a nice ajax replacement, create a very simple *Order total* view with a `Global: Custom text` field (which we'll hide with a css class, just to have the minimum :one field) and put `Commerce Order: Order total` field in footer.

Then alter the form and setup the ajax callback :

```
function vts_insurance_form_views_form_cart_field_assurances_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //add ajax to our field
  $form['field_order_assurances'][0]['field_order_assurances']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'vts_insurance_cart_refresh', 
    'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber', 'message' => ''),
  );
  //unset unused buttons
  unset($form['field_order_assurances'][0]['actions']['submit']);
  unset($form['actions']);
}

function vts_insurance_cart_refresh(&$form, &$form_state) {  
  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($GLOBALS['user']->uid);

  //set the order insurance field value & save it
  $order->field_order_assurances['und'][0]['tid'] = $form_state['values']['field_order_assurances'][0]['field_order_assurances']['und'][0]['tid'];
  commerce_order_save($order);
  commerce_cart_order_refresh($order);

  //Display a message to customer
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($order->field_order_assurances['und'][0]['tid']);
  dsm(t('Insurance : you selected ').$term->name);
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.messages.status', theme('status_messages'));

  //Refresh the cart total display
  $cart_total = commerce_embed_view('shopping_cart_total', 'block', array($order->order_id));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.view-shopping-cart-total', $cart_total);

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

In the module js file, play with your DOM elements to display them as wished

```
(function ($) {

  $(document).ready(function(){
    //A wrapper for the first shopping cart total refresh                   
    $('.commerce-order-handler-area-order-total').wrap('<div class="view-shopping-cart-total"></div>');
    //Move the editable field above buttons
    var assurances = $('.view-id-cart_field_assurances').detach();
    $('.view-shopping-cart-total').before(assurances);
    //A wrapper for ajax messages
    var insurance_message = $("<div class='messages status insurance'></div>");
    insurance_message.appendTo(assurances).hide();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

A rule setting up a ***Fee*** price component, depending on the insurance field percentage value.

```
{ "rules_calcul_des_assurances" : {
    "LABEL" : "Calcul des assurances",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Commerce Cart" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce", "rules", "commerce_fees" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_fees_order" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_exists" : {
          "type" : "commerce_order",
          "property" : "order_id",
          "value" : [ "commerce-order:order-id" ]
        }
      },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ], "field" : "field_order_assurances" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_calc" : {
          "USING" : {
            "input_1" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-order-total:amount-decimal" ],
            "op" : "*",
            "input_2" : [ "commerce-order:field-order-assurances:field-pourcentage" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "assurance_cout" : "Co\u00fbt de l\u0027assurance" } }
        }
      },
      { "commerce_fees_apply" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ],
          "fee" : "assurances",
          "amount" : [ "assurance-cout" ],
          "currency_code" : "EUR"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With such implementation, it is possible to add *any kind of field* in the shopping cart footer, allowing customers to choose options that will *change the order total* adding a price component, with *Ajax* feature. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you should add some line item to your cart. I would go with a product line item.
So now if you have a product called insurance you need to assign the price of total shopping cart * 0.17 to your insurance product

I would try to put all the heavy lifting to rules module. 
Specially because of the fact rules can / will decide the prices including / exluding taxes.
You can change tax depending on your taxonomy term selection if you choose so. And you could add pricing % to taxonomy fields.

Or another and maybe even better way could be https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees

Comment: Thank you. Where would you put the editable field then to allow customer to choose insurance ? Could you develop your *product line item* solution with more details, a short step by step ? Because at the moment I'm afraid I don't really understand it. Be sure I've been searching a lot and I even tried Fees...